# Why are my nodes not appearing in SpriteKit template?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm using Xcode 6 and I started a project with the SpriteKit template.  To start, all I wanted to do was add a node to the bottom left of the provided view.  I attempted to do so like this:

```
@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
/* Setup your scene here */
SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];


SKSpriteNode *greenNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

greenNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);

greenNode.position = CGPointMake(10,10);
[self addChild:greenNode];
```

It is nowhere to be found.  But if I set it's position like this:

```
greenNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                               CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
```

It sits nicely in the middle of my view.  Why don't I see it when I use (10,10) or (0,0).  I actually do see it at the bottom left if I set CGPoint to (350,0).  So, my question is, why in this default template is my node being placed 350 to the left?  I did not change anything in this template.  I feel like it has something to do with this line of code provided in the view controller's viewdidload:

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

But what's the purpose of this?  Any help for a newbie?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspectFill will cause some scenes to have invisible content. For example, say your scene is 1000 * 800, but it moves to a view that is 400 * 400. That would cause your scene to be scaled down to 500 * 400. This means that the 50 points to the left of your scene and 50 points to the right of your scene are invisible. In order to avoid this, you could set your scale mode to AspectFit.

Comment: That worked.  And I see that my view controller was set to 600x600 by default.  I would think it would be set to the phone's dimensions by default?

Comment: You're using XCode 6. Your phone's screen is not 600*600, but "Any x Any" is set to 600 x 600 by default. So, say your phone screen is 320 * 480, that means your view controller will be 320 * 480, but your scene does not have any layout constraints, so it will be set to whatever value you have for it in the storyboard (which I assume you're using). You should add auto layout constraints. For more info, look up "size classes XCode 6", as they are a new feature. Also, this blog post may be helpful: http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/12/size-classes-with-xcode-6-and-swift